# Element in Wadl representation

Tags: rest, xsd, cxf, jax-rs, wadl

I have an JAX-RS API and I'm generating wadl for it.

```
<application ....
    ..
    <request>
        <representation mediaType="application/xml"/>
    </request>
..
</application>
```

But I want add element to representation to it.

```
<application ....
    ..
    <request>
        <representation mediaType="application/xml" element="prefix1:thebook"/>
    </request>
    ..
</application>
```

`thebook` should present in grammar.

My Service:

```
@Path("/update/book")
@POST
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@ElementClass(request = Book.class)
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
String updateBook(Book book);
```

Book.java

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "inventoryBean")
public class Book {
    private Long name;
    private Long id;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There has to be a namespace declared somewhere, either in 
`@XmlRootElement` itself or in a package-level annotation, please add it 
and you should see a proper link to a schema element;
In this case `@XmlRootElement(name = "inventoryBean", namespace = "bean")` should do the job.

Comment: what would be element="" if I need List<Book> ?

Comment: You need to add List<Book> to another class